# How to install a wsdl connection in react-native

Tags: node.js, asp.net-mvc, react-native, node-modules

I'm trying to establish aa wsdl connection. I get the following error. is there anyone who can help?

my connection code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';

    var soap = require('soap');
     var url = 'https://localhost:44379/service/ozelekranservice.svc?wsdl';
    var args = {User : '15460036927', Password : '123'};


type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {

  render() {

    soap.createClientAsync(url).then((client) => {

     console.warn(client.Login(args));

    return client.Login(args);

  }).then((result) => {

   console.warn(result);

   });


    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

> error code
>   url:http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.delta?platform=andoid&dev=true&minify=false
>   body:{"orginModulePath":"

C:\users\...\node_modules\soap\lib\client.js","targetModuleName":"assert","message":"Unable to resolve module'assert'from

'C:\users\...\node_modules\soap\lib\client.js':Module 'assert' does not exist in the Haste module map\n\nThis might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968\nTo resolve try the following:\n

1. Clear watchman watches:'watchman watch-del-all'.\n
2. Delete the 'node_modules' folder: 'rm -rf node_modules &&nom install'.\n

3.Reset Metro Bundler cache:'rm -rf/tmp/metro-bundler-chace-*' or 'npm start -- --reset-chace'.\n

4. Remove haste chace:'rm -rf /tmp/haste-mat-react-native-packager-*'.","errors":[{"description":"Unable to resolve module 'assert'from

'C:\users\...\node_modules\soap\lib\client.js': Module 'assert' does not exist in the Haste module map\n\nThis might be related to

Comment: use your IP address instead of localhost

Comment: still getting the same error